# Append Date/Unique Identifier to File & Move It

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have developed a simple batch file which I want to set up as a scheduled task to move a file.

Currently, this is my code;

```
move /-y "C:\Folder\Folder\Folder\*File*.csv" "C:\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\File.csv"

pause
```

However, this will obviously lead to duplicates (and an overwriting conflict after the second transfer)

How do I append a date (The file will only be moved once daily) or unique identifier to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
 move /-y "C:\Folder\Folder\Folder\*File*.csv" "C:\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\File_%date:~6,4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2%.csv"
```

Note: the numbers 6,4 3,2 0,2 in above commands depend on your date formatting. Check your control panel (or use `echo %date%`) for your default date format. Off course, you can change the order :-)

My default date formatting is DD/MM/YYYY & this snippet changes it to YYYY_MM_DD

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do something like this to append the date time to the file name...

for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%d in ("%date%") do rename "C:\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\File.csv" %%e-%%f-%%g.csv

test - created test.txt on desktop ran .bat (changed file name and location to match the name and location of my test file in the .bat file of course.)

after i ran the .bat the file name was changed to 11-06-2012.txt.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple but the solution is ugly in batch. For example, one of the answers listed above produced the following output for me:

```
C:\>echo %date:~6,4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2%
/08/_ 1_Th
```

Obviously, it doesn't always work. Fortunately, Rob Van der Woude has prepared and collected solutions [such as this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetimentparse.php). That code produces the following output for me:

```
DateParsed=20121108
```

I've copied Rob's code and referenced his source here for ease of use.

```
:: One of the ugliest scripts required for such a seemingly simple thing is getting dates parsed
:: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetimentparse.php
SET Today=%Date: =0%
SET Year=%Today:~-4%
:: Include 1 extra character, which will be either a leading zero or a trailing separator
SET Month=%Today:~-10,3%
:: Remove separator
SET Month=%Month:-=%
SET Month=%Month:/=%
:: Clear leading zeroes

SET /A Month = 100%Month% %% 100
:: And add one again, if necessary
SET /A Month = 100 + %Month%
SET Month=%Month:~-2%
SET Day=%Today:~-7,2%
:: Remove separator
SET Day=%Day:-=%
SET Day=%Day:/=%
:: Clear leading zeroes, as there may be 2 leading zeroes
SET /A Day = 100%Day% %% 100
:: And add one again, if necessary
SET /A Day = 100 + %Day%
SET Day=%Day:~-2%

SET DateParsed=%year%%month%%day%
echo DateParsed=%DateParsed%
```